# XAML serialization of third-party types

Tags: c#, xaml, serialization, xamarin.forms

To be specific, I'm trying to serialize a resource dictionary containing a bunch of `Xamarin.Forms.Color` objects:

```
ResourceDictionary resources = ...
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings)) {
     XamlServices.Save(writer, resources);
}
```

The problem is that the resulting XAML for each color is an empty node:

```
<Color x:Key="SomeColor" />
```

`System.Xaml` seems to have rather limited support for this kind of thing; I can't use `TypeConverter` or `ValueSerializer` attributes since I don't own the type.

I've been digging through the documentation (which also seems to be lacking) and I can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about how you're trying to serialize TO xaml, and what would be missing for you to get it working? I'm afraid you'll have to resort to manual serialization, but we can look at adding the right attributes to future versions of Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix Thank you. I've added a little info to the question. As of now, I do have it working using a custom implementation of `XamlXmlWriter.WriteNode` but it would be nice if it worked out of the box.